# The coskewness and cokurtosis of uncorrelated standardized random vector

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, principal-component-analysis

I was conducting the Karhunen-Loeve (K-L) Expansion for a random vector.

Based on the KL expansion, I transformed the original random vector into a standardized random vector $\boldsymbol{X}=[X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n]$ with zero mean and identity covariance. Now I am wondering whether there are some relationships I can get for the coskewness and cokurtosis, i.e., $\mathbb{E}(X_iX_jX_k)$ and $\mathbb{E}(X_jX_jX_kX_l),\;\forall i,j,k,l$. Do these values become very small or zero when the random variables are uncorrelated?

Anything inspiring will be appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: For different $i,j,k,l$ they are obviously zero. Can you proceed?

Comment: @KurtG. Many thanks in advance. Can you provide some more proof for this conclusion? I want to arrive at a similar conclusion but failed to prove it.

Comment: The expectations factorize due to independence. Then use zero mean.

Comment: @KurtG. But these variables are only uncorrelated by KL expansion, not necessarily independent. In this case, I think the expectations cannot factorize